# Processing BigInteger issues

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger, diffie-hellman

Assume the following Diffie-Hellman info which can also be found on this [page](http://sandilands.info/sgordon/diffie-hellman-secret-key-exchange-with-openssl)

**1)P**

```
string givenp = "00e655cc9e04f3bebae76ecca77143ef5c4451876615a9f8b4f712b8f3bdf47ee7f717c09bb5b2b66450831367d9dcf85f9f0528bcd5318fb1dab2f23ce77c48b6b7381eed13e80a14cca6b30b5e37ffe53db15e2d6b727a2efcee51893678d50e9a89166a359e574c4c3ca5e59fae79924fe6f186b36a2ebde9bf09fe4de50453";
        BigInteger p = new BigInteger(HexToBytesv2(givenp));
```

**2)G**

```
BigInteger g = new BigInteger(2);
```

**3)Merchant  private key**

```
string merchantPrivateKeyHEX = "48887dfd090d175e33beea29e7b38334299289069f9ab492b67807905faa98d96d22d79205bef03f14af093f1797b904734132c34a388fdc79e20497bfa1465fec2aac4fabdf3bb0c9be8685d20f7bfe0346a9abdf7fa89838c3fa9ca6abdb70bea66795ab6699cc154db59490e4159f142f7bddff603c1d3d6c4fff8177e11d";
        BigInteger a = new BigInteger(HexToBytesv2(merchantPrivateKeyHEX));
```

Using the formula `publickey = g ^ a mod p` I should get the public key provided in the initial link, yet when executing

```
BigInteger A = BigInteger.ModPow(g, a, p);
ToHex(A.ToByteArray())
```

the result I get is

```
00f85c41e84446ecfe43c9911df31d3cf60d83642afd496b741363290139badf75f8b8c5c010dda2446dd483dc553b6c2698c16c9d082391677785f81d54bc9c7c45f8b6d5bdb3e49fec7f5522b880c8c753fb7d3ff2c81e47dcb27d52842def40a812dc95cc679575baf237a955ee9944bd0797326f2a0a58c6c087f9b0b9e82c
```

instead of

```
00d9abd78c93dfddeb920d57d6513126d8f1118c9237a45101408dbffe6cfd95b011a016e4e0ab8aef0601e836a452b8bb88be7ca71e4f22f97aa65f8358ee69348d1227d65db6e53641d1a6542aa4be4b4adc75fac816af79a8e3f5097f8313e7b725df37eadc8c774e2033dfa99c95ccef333bf402b066198c30481e2a83875c
```

Any ideas? I must be missing pretty obvious but I am not sure what that might be.

P.S. Adding the function being used:

```
 public static byte[] HexToBytesv2(this string hex)
    {
        if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
            hex = '0' + hex;

        byte[] ret = new byte[hex.Length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < ret.Length; i++)
            ret[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);

        return ret;

    }

  public static string ToHex(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in ba)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: How is this related to Diffie Hellman ? Have you encountered an error you assumed is caused by some problem in how bitwise operations are performed? Why aren't you using .NET's built-in cryptography, or the [OpenSSL.Net](https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net) library?

Comment: The algorithm used is the Diffie Hellman algorithm. Due to lack of examples online, this was the easiest way for me to go.

Comment: The question shows just a Hex2Byte conversion and back, this isn't related to DH. As for examples, googling for "Diffie Hellman c#" returns the [ECDiffieHellmanCng Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng(v=vs.110).aspx) with various examples in the Remarks section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an endian problem.

I've adjusted your encoding and decoding and now get the answer you're looking for:

```
public static byte[] HexToBytesv2(string hex)
{
    if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
        hex = '0' + hex;

    byte[] ret = new byte[hex.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < ret.Length; i++)
        ret[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(hex.Length - (i+1) * 2, 2), 16);

    return ret;

}

public static string ToHex( byte[] bytes)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var b in bytes.Reverse())
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

FYI I used LinqPad and the main method is your code from the question (as adjusted) with checks that the data has not lost anything on the way:

```
void Main()
{
    string givenp = "00e655cc9e04f3bebae76ecca77143ef5c4451876615a9f8b4f712b8f3bdf47ee7f717c09bb5b2b66450831367d9dcf85f9f0528bcd5318fb1dab2f23ce77c48b6b7381eed13e80a14cca6b30b5e37ffe53db15e2d6b727a2efcee51893678d50e9a89166a359e574c4c3ca5e59fae79924fe6f186b36a2ebde9bf09fe4de50453";
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(HexToBytesv2(givenp));
    (ToHex(p.ToByteArray()) == "00e655cc9e04f3bebae76ecca77143ef5c4451876615a9f8b4f712b8f3bdf47ee7f717c09bb5b2b66450831367d9dcf85f9f0528bcd5318fb1dab2f23ce77c48b6b7381eed13e80a14cca6b30b5e37ffe53db15e2d6b727a2efcee51893678d50e9a89166a359e574c4c3ca5e59fae79924fe6f186b36a2ebde9bf09fe4de50453").Dump();
    BigInteger g = new BigInteger(2);
    string merchantPrivateKeyHEX = "48887dfd090d175e33beea29e7b38334299289069f9ab492b67807905faa98d96d22d79205bef03f14af093f1797b904734132c34a388fdc79e20497bfa1465fec2aac4fabdf3bb0c9be8685d20f7bfe0346a9abdf7fa89838c3fa9ca6abdb70bea66795ab6699cc154db59490e4159f142f7bddff603c1d3d6c4fff8177e11d";
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger(HexToBytesv2(merchantPrivateKeyHEX));
    (ToHex(a.ToByteArray()) == "48887dfd090d175e33beea29e7b38334299289069f9ab492b67807905faa98d96d22d79205bef03f14af093f1797b904734132c34a388fdc79e20497bfa1465fec2aac4fabdf3bb0c9be8685d20f7bfe0346a9abdf7fa89838c3fa9ca6abdb70bea66795ab6699cc154db59490e4159f142f7bddff603c1d3d6c4fff8177e11d").Dump();
    BigInteger A = BigInteger.ModPow(g, a, p);
    (ToHex(A.ToByteArray()) == "00f85c41e84446ecfe43c9911df31d3cf60d83642afd496b741363290139badf75f8b8c5c010dda2446dd483dc553b6c2698c16c9d082391677785f81d54bc9c7c45f8b6d5bdb3e49fec7f5522b880c8c753fb7d3ff2c81e47dcb27d52842def40a812dc95cc679575baf237a955ee9944bd0797326f2a0a58c6c087f9b0b9e82c").Dump();
    (ToHex(A.ToByteArray()) == "00d9abd78c93dfddeb920d57d6513126d8f1118c9237a45101408dbffe6cfd95b011a016e4e0ab8aef0601e836a452b8bb88be7ca71e4f22f97aa65f8358ee69348d1227d65db6e53641d1a6542aa4be4b4adc75fac816af79a8e3f5097f8313e7b725df37eadc8c774e2033dfa99c95ccef333bf402b066198c30481e2a83875c").Dump();
}
```

Before I swapped the ordering, and included the `.Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray()` from your original question, the output was:

```
True
True
True
False
```

And now it's:

```
True
True
False
True
```

The other issue you're seeing is `BigInteger.Parse` and the `Byte[]` constructor always expect the top bit of the first nibble or last byte respectively to be the sign bit. So you need to include the extra `0` character or byte respectively to avoid that.

Comment: This indeed works well, but only when i attach a 0 byte when creating the BigInteger like    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(HexToBytesv2(givenp).Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray()); The produced public key starts of course with "00" but other than that it's correct. If i don't include the zero byte, then it does not work at all. I will mark your answer as the correct still if nothing better comes up

Comment: It works just as well for me when I delete the `.Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray()` (that you originally had in your question).

Comment: It is true, this example works as well, maybe because the resulting public key already starts with "00". Any idea why it does not for this input: http://pastebin.com/Ry18dQF5?

Comment: What are you expecting? I get `049cc92b93214bbf3785b2391f164b6a4a194c419d2299ca14eb1ac7c026827788e008a3a6dc9aa5a9520d39963ccb23fb173fdca8f93b0b507d2cdb1d6b22c912e861f55b6ec8b5d733563957ecb7daee8f8cde4cacf285d204dd72307db9b8a75481574ce8e0eecfd8c8e75e37c17d19ac8606882b4e983f46d7127967a0b2`.

Comment: yeah good point, the result should be     85f04dd00345642ad12b65bd1a7c38728bff0b8e281ddb
6ac4f2739e82a02145daabf23d173c933913b1f8440597 
10e9125591569de427eae1d269accbfa3305069deb7622 
d1da3ad9820d11bd24fdcce5381d2df99bda314394738d 
fcbe210eae247b1303e79297ff746cd919e189f6a5776e 
6ecc24c8900de0f38f159072de    If you add the empty byte it looks like that

Comment: Haven't got time to further look into it now, but using LukeH's code but with the numbers from pastebin, with `00` prepended to only `givenp` I get the number you're expecting. I haven't looked into what BigInteger is expecting in its bytes, but `var p = BigInteger.Parse(givenp, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var pdash = BigInteger.Parse("00"+givenp, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var q=pdash/p;
var r=pdash%p;` produces a non-zero value for `r` and `q` is `-8` (for the `givenp` from pastebin)!

Answer (score 3):

You're doing a number of unnecessary conversions and they're introducing an error somewhere.

If you remove the broken `string`-`byte[]`-`BigInteger`-`byte[]`-`string` steps and let `BigInteger` itself do the work for you then you'll generate the expected result:

```
string givenp = "00e655cc9e04f3bebae76ecca77143ef5c4451876615a9f8b4f712b8f3bdf47ee7f717c09bb5b2b66450831367d9dcf85f9f0528bcd5318fb1dab2f23ce77c48b6b7381eed13e80a14cca6b30b5e37ffe53db15e2d6b727a2efcee51893678d50e9a89166a359e574c4c3ca5e59fae79924fe6f186b36a2ebde9bf09fe4de50453";
var p = BigInteger.Parse(givenp, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

var g = new BigInteger(2);

var merchantPrivateKeyHEX = "48887dfd090d175e33beea29e7b38334299289069f9ab492b67807905faa98d96d22d79205bef03f14af093f1797b904734132c34a388fdc79e20497bfa1465fec2aac4fabdf3bb0c9be8685d20f7bfe0346a9abdf7fa89838c3fa9ca6abdb70bea66795ab6699cc154db59490e4159f142f7bddff603c1d3d6c4fff8177e11d";
var a = BigInteger.Parse(merchantPrivateKeyHEX, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

var publicKey = BigInteger.ModPow(g, a, p);
Console.WriteLine(publicKey.ToString("x"));  // displays 0d9abd7...
```

Comment: While you are right about unnecessary conversions, they are not the ones that cause the problem. Still get the problem after the proposed changes.