# Java vs C# BigInteger Producing different values

Tags: java, c#

I am having some trouble with producing the same BigInteger value in C# as I get in Java.  In both languages I am creating the BigIntegers from an array of bytes which hold the same values, in the same order.

The Java BigInteger is created like so:

```
BigInteger hashnum = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
```

And produces:
79054595997078811232777738014361687045908459940911070866043475968067897954324

md.digest() returns the following values in both languages:
{-73, 97, 1, -64, 23, 38, 69, 95, 107, 122, 119, -122, -99, -92, 47, 8, -118, 70, 119, 98, 64, -1, -70, 36}

My C# code:

With adding 0 byte to end, but not reversing the byte array

```
sbyte[] hashSBytes = md.digest();
if ((hashSBytes[hashSBytes.Length - 1] & 0x80) != 0)
{
   Array.Resize<sbyte>(ref hashSBytes, hashSBytes.Length + 1);
}
BigInteger hashnum = new BigInteger((byte[])(object)hashSBytes);
```

The BigInteger has a value of 92590942655695057524171612499701658178022831645290183610636811349839086444983

With adding 0 byte AND reversing the byte array

```
sbyte[] hashSBytes = md.digest();
Array.Reverse(hashSBytes);
if ((hashSBytes[hashSBytes.Length - 1] & 0x80) != 0)
{
   Array.Resize<sbyte>(ref hashSBytes, hashSBytes.Length + 1);
}
BigInteger hashnum = new BigInteger((byte[])(object)hashSBytes);
```

The BigInteger has a value of 82944647536515285715130977031103916663496217450446852247301410452203227690188

Comment: Without seeing the code for either C# or Java, we cannot possibly offer any answers.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **("why isn't this code working?")** must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and the _shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java BigInteger vs Mono .net BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119032/java-biginteger-vs-mono-net-biginteger) Although this question references mono, it should apply to .net as well.

Comment: @hatchet I have taken a look at the possible duplicate you mentioned.  My values are already in the same order but I see that person solved their problem by adding the 0 byte to the beginning rather than the end as I have done.  Is this another difference between big vs little endian? Not only do I need to have the value in the same order but the bit c# will look for is the first instead of the last for the sign?

Comment: The 0 byte is a _different_ element from the byte order. I.e. you need to comply with both requirements. _"the array was constructed to already be in the same order as the Java array"_ -- but that's just it. The two platforms require different orderings for the byte array. You can't pass the Java-ordered array to the .NET version of `BitInteger`. You do need to fix your question so that it has a good [mcve], if simply reversing the order of the array on .NET doesn't correct your problem.

Comment: I am not sure what else to provide. I have provided how I am creating the BigInteger, the exact values of the array, and the results when I do and do not reverse the order of the byte array, as well as when I do and do not add the 0 byte.

Comment: _"I am not sure what else to provide"_ -- read [mcve]. It spells it all out for you. See also [ask], including the articles linked at the bottom of that page. Your question looks nothing like what's recommended at those references.

Comment: I have rewritten the question, hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: The `(byte[])(object)` hack is invalid. Not every `sbyte` can be converted to `byte`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My C# code was working properly all along. The java result I was trying to match was wrong. md.digest() was being called 2 times in the java code but it is non-static and wasn't being reset in between. The first call wasn't even supposed to be there, it was just for debugging so that I could assign it to a property and see the value in the debugger since the BigInteger constructor was using md.digest() directly.  I failed to reset the array in this non-static class after my debug line called the method, so even though I was seeing the same values in the debugger at this line, when it actually created the BigInteger and called md.digest() the 2nd time it was receiving different values.

Answer (score 3):

Before you continue your bashing of the "SO point nazis" on SitePoint, I think you are doing something wrong elsewhere. When you take your big integer as string and parse it in JAVA and C#, you get the exact same result when you project to a byte array.

`00,AE,C7,50,D1,1F,EE,E9,F1,62,71,92,2F,BA,F5,A9,BE,14,2F,62,01,9E,F8,D7,20,F8,58,94,00,70,88,90,14`

You are right, reversed in C#, but still the same.

**C#**

```
var bi = BigInteger.Parse("79054595997078811232777738014361687045908459940911070866043475968067897954324");
Console.WriteLine(
  String.Join(",", 
    bi.ToByteArray().Reverse().Select(s=>s.ToString("X2"))));
```

**JAVA**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigIntSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("79054595997078811232777738014361687045908459940911070866043475968067897954324");
        byte[] bytes = bi.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(byteArrayToHex(bytes));
    }

    public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
        for (byte b : a)
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", b).concat(","));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I believe the main problem is that in C# you are processing `sbyte`s, signed bytes, which have a totally different meaning than `byte`s. I might be wrong, but definitely not a "point nazi".

**PEACE**